# Submit a dynamically created table in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dynamically created table inside a `form_for`. The table consists of an input field in each row. The number of rows inside the table is not constant (and hence the table is created dynamically).

How do I submit all the fields inside the table and route it to a controller action?

Comment: please describe your needs more clearly

Comment: Done. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: you should provide information what is the logic behind that input fields that are not "constant". what are data types? (array, string/numeric). 
however try this fiddle and let me know if it fits your needs. then i'll help you to set up routes/controllers etc. https://jsfiddle.net/s2L08mzt/

Answer (score 0):

You can customize where send your data with **url** param in **form_for** helper.

```
<%= form_for @article, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
...
```

Submit button will send all your rows at method *"create" of ArticlesController*

```
form_for(@article, url: my_custompath_articles_path)
...
```

your data will be transmitted where declared by **my_custompath_articles_path** in

```
config/routes.rb

resources :articles do
  collection do
    post my_custompath
  end
end
```

and

```
articles_controller.rb

def my_custompath
  ... your code
end
```

more detailed informations at [ruby on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

I hope this can hep you.